# IIS 8.5, Win Srvr 2012 R2 - CustomError mode=Off does not work, Blank page

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc, custom-errors

We have an MVC ASP.net app on IIS 8.5, Win Server 2012 R2.

When we set web.config to:

`<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/error" ></customErrors>`

The site shows completely blank when there's an error.

Searching around I found that perhaps it might be because the app pool identity was set on site folder permission and indeed it wasn't, so I set it but that still did not fix it. It is set to Full Rights.

All other IIS settings for site are correct as far as I can tell, Windows Auth enabled, 32 bit site = True...

Anyone have any advice about what direction I could go next?

Thanks!